# Python logging message not getting output as expected in simplest scenario

Tags: python, logging

I am not getting any output from `logging.debug` in the simplest possible situation. (I do get output from `logger.warn`.)

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.warn('Logger is warning')
logger.debug('Logger is debugging')
print(logger.getEffectiveLevel(),
      logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG),
      file=sys.stderr)
```

The last line prints the logger's logging level, which shows as `logging.DEBUG`, and whether the logger is enabled for that level, which is true. yet output appears for `log.warn` but not for `log.debug`. What am I missing?

[Python 3.5, OS X 10.11]

Comment: What is your handler?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you haven't specified a handler. On Python 3.5, an internal ["handler of last resort"](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/logging.html#logging.lastResort) is used when no handler is specified by you, but that internal handler has a level of `WARNING` and so won't show messages of lower severity. You need to specify a handler and add it like this example:

```
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

either just before or just after the `setLevel` statement in your snippet.

Comment: Yup, that worked. Thanks. But my reading of the basic tutorial in the documentation of the logging model [https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial] suggests I can set the level of the default logger with the default handler and not have to add a handler.

  [1]: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial